# beagleboard xubuntu s-video to TV

Tags: beagleboard, ubuntu-12.10, xfce

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 on a Beagleboard xM with Xfce 4.10 as the desktop gui.  For some reason a TV I need to hook it up to doesn't display the DVI-D output using an HDMI cable, but a newer TV works no problem.  So, I'm trying to get s-video output working so I can still use the older TV.

I can see the s-video output when the Beagleboard is booting and it is just text on the screen, but it appears that the output signal is lost when Xfce starts loading.  I've read a lot of different posts about making the output go over s-video rather than dvi, which is the default, but I can't seem to get it to work completely.  I've edited /boot/uboot/uEnv.txt to make s-video the default.  As a result of the edits, this is what I see for my boot args when I `cat /proc/cmdline`

```
console=ttyS2,115200n8 console=tty0 vram=12MB omapfb.mode=tv:ntsc omapdss.def_disp=tv root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 ro rootfstype=ext4 rootwait fixrtc buddy=unknown buddy2=unknown camera=none
```

Some posts I read advise creating a boot.scr file, which I did but it is ignored.  The only way I can get the boot args to change is by editing uEnv.txt.

I am not a Linux expert, so hopefully it's something simple that I'm missing.  Thanks!